# How to create a dictionary from a CSV file, appending multiple values to three keys?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to be able to append multiple values from a `CSV` file to a dictionary that has three keys. The keys are `morning`, `midday`, and `night`. The values should come from each row of the `CSV` file.

Ideally, it should look like below.

I can't use `numpy` or `csv` modules, so those options are not available. It has to work with no imports, and I'm unsure with dictionaries and how to approach this to get the output I need.

Here is a sample of what the `CSV` file looks like:

[image]

```py
{
    'morning': {[5, 5, 10, 17, 20, 21]},
    'midday': {[10, 20, 25, 15, 8, 3]},
    'night': {[3, 5, 2, 7, 15, 29]}
}
```

Here is my code:

```py
time_list = []
time_dict = {}

with open('stats.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    headers = data_file.readline()

    for line in data_file:
        Time, VS = line.split(',')
        time_list.append(int(VS))
        time_dict[Time] = time_dict.get(Time, 0) + int(VS)
```

Appending to the list produces each value like it should, i.e.:

```py
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But for the dictionary, it does not show each value individually for the key it is attached to. Instead, it will take all the values for each key and add them together.

Printing the dictionary shows the following:

```py
{'morning': 2097, 'midday': 1240, 'night': 1533}
```

I'm unsure of how to approach this to get the dictionary to look like the following:

```py
{
    'morning':{[5, 5, 10, 17, 20, 21]},
    'midday': {[10, 20, 25, 15, 8, 3]},
     'night': {[3, 5, 2, 7, 15, 29]}
}
```

Note: Many of the answers I have found use the `csv` module, which I unfortunately cannot use for this. I have to use no imports for this solution.

Also keytype of the dictionary must be int so I can peform math operations on the dictionary to find out the max, min, average etc

Comment: Quick comment: your `dict` is actually not a dictionnary since the value you assigned to it is an invalid `Python` syntax. Perphaps, you mean `{'morning': [5, 5, 10, 17, 20, 21], 'midday': [10, 20, 25, 15, 8, 3], 'night': [3, 5, 2, 7, 15, 29]}`

Comment: yes abokey, that is what I meant, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
import csv 

with open(fn) as csv_in:
    reader=csv.reader(csv_in)
    header=next(reader)
    data={}
    for t,vs in reader:
        data.setdefault(t, []).append(int(vs))
```

---

From comment "I can't use imports":

```
with open(fn) as csv_in:
    header=next(csv_in)
    data={}
    for t,vs in (line.split(',') for line in csv_in):
        data.setdefault(t, []).append(int(vs))
```

From comment "The data is in the eighth column":

With a slight modification (and assuming Python 3) you can set `*vs` so that `vs` accepts a variable number in the expansion:

```
with open(fn) as csv_in:
    header=next(csv_in)
    data={}
    for t,*vs in (line.split(',') for line in csv_in):
        data.setdefault(t, []).append(int(vs[7]))
```

Given this file:

```
Time,VS
morning,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,80
morning,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81
midday,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,90
midday,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,91
night,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100
night,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,101
```

Prints:

```
>>> data
{'morning': [80, 81], 'midday': [90, 91], 'night': [100, 101]}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but unfortunately I cannot use the csv module. has to be done without imports

Comment: I simplified the example data for the post, there are more than two columns, the values I want in the dictionary are in the 8th column, so this approach wouldn't work I think.

Comment: Yes it would. See edit

Comment: Ok I tried it in a new file and it works, I will try configure it to my existing file and get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: Your requirements keep changing.

Comment: I agree with @dawg, so I'm voting to close the question. The answers provided address the question, but OP keeps changing the requirements on the comments.

Comment: Apologies again, if you are reading this the answers from @dawg work, I was rushing and not thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing your strategy and doing it like this:

```
morning_list= []
midday_list= []
night_list= []
time_dict = dict()

with open("stats.csv", "r") as data_file:
    headers = data_file.readline()

    for line in data_file:
        Time, VS = line.split(",")
        if Time == "morning":
           morning_list.append(int(VS))
        elif Time == "midday":
           midday_list.append(int(VS))
        elif Time == "night":
           night_list.append(int(VS))

time_dict["morning"] = morning_list
time_dict["midday"] = midday_list
time_dict["night"] = night_list
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is producing a TypeError for "unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Remove the curly brackets around all the lists at the end